Flutter image generation in background
Is it possible to generate (and save as an image) interface or individual flutter widgets without displaying the program, in the background / console utility? For windows/Linux.
While this is a working variant, the program is still displayed:
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  const test = Text(
    'Hello, World!',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
  );

  final boundaryKey = GlobalKey();
  final RepaintBoundary repaintBoundary = RepaintBoundary(
    key: boundaryKey,
    child: test,
  );

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    var formatter = DateFormat('hh.mm.ss');
    String formattedDate = formatter.format(now);
    print(formattedDate);

    final RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        boundaryKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
    final image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
    final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    final pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

    final file = File('results/$formattedDate.png');
    await file.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);

    print('Image saved to: ${file.path}');
  });

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: repaintBoundary));
}



Thanks to spauldhaliwal
Here is how I did it:
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';

void main() async {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final ScreenshotController screenshotController = ScreenshotController();

  void saveCapturedWidget(Uint8List capturedImage) {
    final file = File('results/my_image.jpg');
    file.writeAsBytesSync(capturedImage);
    print('Image saved to: ${file.path}');
  }

  const double widgetWidth = 200.0;
  const double widgetHeight = 200.0;

  Widget invisibleWidget = Container(
    width: widgetWidth,
    height: widgetHeight,
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: const Center(
      child: Text(
        'Invisible Widget',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
      ),
    ),
  );

  final capturedImage = await screenshotController.captureFromWidget(
    invisibleWidget,
    targetSize: const Size(widgetWidth, widgetHeight),
    pixelRatio: 1.0,
  );

  saveCapturedWidget(capturedImage);

  print('Image generation completed. Exiting...');
  exit(0);
}

